# random.choice raises KeyError when called on nodes of a NodeView object

Tags: python

I am trying to select one of the elements out of a group of nodes (`G.nodes()`) but not getting the output. Instead getting errors. Below are the details. I am using Python 3.6

When `G` is:

```
Out[36]: NodeView(('Delhi', 'Bangalore', 'Hyderabad', 'Ahmedabad', 'Chennai', 'Kolkatta', 'Surat', 'Pune', 'Jaipur'))
```

code:

```
c1=random.choice(G.nodes())

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-43-8dfc19a66804>", line 1, in <module>
    c1=random.choice(G.nodes())

  File "C:\Users\prasa\Anaconda3\lib\random.py", line 259, in choice
    return seq[i]

  File "C:\Users\prasa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py", line 178, in __getitem__
    return self._nodes[n]

KeyError: 5
```

Comment: I have gone through a video in which the o/p was obtained with the earlier format, I didn't get the same. With your help I got the output. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using networkx. Looking up the documentation for `Graph` I can see that it says this:

> A NodeView of the Graph as G.nodes or G.nodes().
>
> Can be used as `G.nodes` **for data lookup and for set-like operations.**
>
> [...]
>
> Returns
>
> ---
>
> NodeView
>    **Allows set-like operations over the
>   nodes as well as node   attribute dict lookup and calling to get a
>   NodeDataView.**   A NodeDataView iterates over `(n, data)` and has no
>   set operations.   A NodeView iterates over `n` and includes set
>   operations.

However `random.choice` needs a **sequence** not a **set**/map-like object. You can obtain a sequence by simply calling `list`:

```
random.choice(list(G.nodes()))
```

The error is due to the fact that the `NodeView` is not indexed by the position of the nodes in the set, hence when `random.choice` generates the random index (according to the number of nodes present) to return the random node it fails with that `KeyError`.